# Triggering a target=_blank link from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is a nasty one.

I have an external link.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
```

now I want to track a Google AdWords conversion every time that link gets clicked.

To do that, I add a `click` event that loads a Google image. The image counts the conversion. To make absolutely sure the image gets loaded before the user leaves, I use the image's `load` event to proceed to the original link's target.

```
$("#linkname").click(function() {

 var element = document.createElement("img");
 element.onload = function() { ..... };
 element.setAttribute("src", "http://www.googleadservices.com/....");
 document.body.appendChild(element); 

 });
```

This will work fine using `location.href`. However, it won't work for `target="blank"` links.
 I'm baffled as to *what to put into the onload function in order to open a new window.*

- I can't use `window.open` because it will be caught by pop-up blockers (Because it's located in the image's `onload` event, it looks like a purely programmatical call that has nothing to do with the link being clicked.) Also, calling window.open without any options does not give me any controls in Google Chrome.
- I can't make the `click` event continue its normal course because I have to wait until the image is loaded, which is an asynchronous operation!

What I would need, essentially, is a way to open a `target="_blank"` link programmatically, something that may not be possible because it could be circumvented by pop-up-blocker-breakers.

Alternatively, I would need a way to reliably count hits while letting the link's original `click` event continue as it's supposed to.

Does anybody have an idea what to do?

Comment: Since the link opens in new window, you don't really have to wait for the image to load. Let the image load in the current window (as is being done) and let the user see the new window as normal. It would be very unlikely that the user can close the window before the image is loaded, thus the count would not be disturbed.

Comment: @amit that was the **exact** realization I had just now. A total case of over-complication :) Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: sometimes we need second pair of eyes :)

Comment: Does Google not provide a JavaScript call for explicit tracking of links? I know they do for Google Analytics (i.e. `onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/outgoing/facebook')"`). I'm surprised that you have to roll your own.

Comment: @Mark I was as surprised as you, but they indeed don't seem to. I searched high and low in Google's docs, the image is the best there is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the link opens in new window, you don't really have to wait for the image to load. Let the image load in the current window (as is being done) and let the user see the new window as normal. It would be very unlikely that the user can close the window before the image is loaded, thus the count would not be disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work or if you can (because of some requirement) do this but:

Try to open a new window with no location, but on the real click event (not in the onload of the image), but open this window with width and height 0, and puts its x and y in somewhere not visible by the user, or less visible as possible.
Keep a reference to this window.

On the onload event of your image, change the location of the new window's url, and then resize and reposition the new window.

Hope it works.

Comment: Turns out I totally overcomplicated the issue: See @amit's comment above, I can proceed with the link straight away, no need to wait. Thanks for your time anyway!